# Laptop LCD flickers on one side

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, lcd

I have a Thinkpad T440s with an AUO IPS 1920x1080 screen which I fitted myself a few years ago (as the laptop fitted with an inferior LG model).

Often about a third of the screen on the far left will flicker. Its brightness will fluctuate between the brightness of the remaining two thirds (on the right) and what appears to be maximum brightness. The full height of the screen flickers and the flickering brightness is uniform over this area.

Putting manual pressure on the bottom bezel at approximately where the line of delineation occurs between the flickering area and the non-flickering area, prevents the flickering. I have tried removing the bezel, and at this area of the screen there is a kind of membrane which says "DO NOT TOUCH" on it.

I went ahead and ignored the no touching warning, and it "feels" like there are components beneath this area, such as resistors or capacitors (just guessing from the topology - I haven't removed the membrane to see underneath).

What could be causing this?

Comment: Sounds more like the screen is defective, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

does it flicker or get better when you open/close the screen a little bit?
I had a similar problem with my HP Pavilion and it was a faulty VGA flex cable.

Comment: Yes it does indeed. Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: Yes, I replace the cable and problem was gone.
Do you have another cable to try? it does not cost much. I got mine for 6 dollars on eBay.

Comment: I think the cable is integrated with the screen.

Comment: I mean video cable, which connects your screen to the motherboard.
It is folded every time when you close and open your LCD screen. Possibly it is damaged in your laptop.